ubuntu close connectiion when upload to server with scp command
I am copying single file from desktop to remote server with
scp /Users/u2/Documents/yu.csv remote_user@ip:/home/remote_user/yu.csv

In terminal, it just replies with:

scp: Connection closed

I tried to debug it with:
tail -f /var/log/auth.log

Resulting in:
Sep 15 13:45:42 fchannel sshd[3737565]: Accepted publickey for u2 from xxx.132.xxx.107 port 53781 ssh2: RSA SHA256:EcTyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Sep 15 13:45:42 fchannel sshd[3737565]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user u2 by (uid=0)
Sep 15 13:45:42 fchannel systemd-logind[989]: New session 8571 of user u2.
Sep 15 13:45:43 fchannel sshd[3737651]: Received disconnect from xxx.132.xxx.107 port 53781:11: disconnected by user
Sep 15 13:45:43 fchannel sshd[3737651]: Disconnected from user u2 xxx.132.xxx.107 port 53781
Sep 15 13:45:43 fchannel sshd[3737565]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user onenet
Sep 15 13:45:43 fchannel systemd-logind[989]: Session 8571 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Sep 15 13:45:43 fchannel systemd-logind[989]: Removed session 8571.

any help is appreciated.
ssh login works fine.
verbose debug from local machine:
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host xx.xxx.xxx.xx, user onenet, command sftp
OpenSSH_9.7p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xx.xxx.xxx.xx is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: channel_clear_timeouts: clearing
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xxx.xx [xx.xxx.xxx.xx] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.11
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.11 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to xx.xxx.xxx.xx:22 as 'onenet'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 2 keys from xx.xxx.xxx.xx
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug3: kex_choose_conf: will use strict KEX ordering
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:aeQ4gM+lLtyC1nKInx+fcj/ueVT+HzG0cmGNNQWi31E
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 2 keys from xx.xxx.xxx.xx
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug3: kex_input_ext_info: extension server-sig-algs
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Zk1b11Bm8R/Listeners'
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:EcTyzw5kiWDMVr8tNH/27nYhFaU7hPLCbVLth89TUrY
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:EcTyzw5kiWDMVr8tNH/27nYhFaU7hPLCbVLth89TUrY
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:EcTyzw5kiWDMVr8tNH/27nYhFaU7hPLCbVLth89TUrY
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with RSA SHA256:EcTyzw5kiWDMVr8tNH/27nYhFaU7hPLCbVLth89TUrY
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:EcTyzw5kiWDMVr8tNH/27nYhFaU7hPLCbVLth89TUrY
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
Authenticated to xx.xxx.xxx.xx ([xx.xxx.xxx.xx]:22) using "publickey".
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new session [client-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received RSA key SHA256:pu91smxD9ndnBMHdCRnLgGFSGy3Fb6U5cjBRjrzaqE8
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ECDSA key SHA256:ErZYo7igtNXGiKCpzODgzgFjzYUxqDz2vhXm9cauPkU
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ED25519 key SHA256:aeQ4gM+lLtyC1nKInx+fcj/ueVT+HzG0cmGNNQWi31E
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts for xx.xxx.xxx.xx / (none)
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-ed25519 key at /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key at /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts2 for xx.xxx.xxx.xx / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: 3 server keys: 1 new, 1 retained, 1 incomplete match. 0 to remove
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: asking server to prove ownership for 1 keys
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/onenet/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/onenet/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x20
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env TERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env __CFBundleIdentifier
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env XPC_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env XPC_SERVICE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env HOMEBREW_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env HOMEBREW_CELLAR
debug3: Ignored env HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY
debug3: Ignored env INFOPATH
debug3: Ignored env HOMEBREW_SHELLENV_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env MANPATH
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_EXE
debug3: Ignored env _CE_M
debug3: Ignored env _CE_CONDA
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PYTHON_EXE
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env _
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug2: channel 0: request subsystem confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 81
debug1: client_global_hostkeys_prove_confirm: server used untrusted RSA signature algorithm ssh-rsa for key 0, disregarding
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: host_delete: ED25519 key already at /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: host_delete: ECDSA key already at /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: update_known_hosts: known hosts file /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug1: pledge: fork
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: subsystem request accepted on channel 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-signal reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 0: (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 [session] r0 i3/9 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1 io 0x00/0x00)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Transferred: sent 4124, received 3640 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 8172.4, received 7213.2
debug1: Exit status -1
scp: Connection closed


Did you try this? (the -O option)


debug1: Server accepts key:

So authentication was successful, but subsequently something else happened. This is confirmed by your auth.log:
Sep 15 13:45:42 fchannel sshd[3737565]: Accepted publickey for u2 from xxx.132.xxx.107 port 53781 ssh2: RSA SHA256:EcTyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Sep 15 13:45:42 fchannel sshd[3737565]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user u2 by (uid=0)
Sep 15 13:45:42 fchannel systemd-logind[989]: New session 8571 of user u2.

Which is consistent with your assertion that:

ssh login works fine.

In your debug output:
receive packet: type 99
...
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-signal reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 96

We are missing some meaning for these numbers....
     SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF                     96     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_CLOSE                   97     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST                 98     [SSH-CONNECT]
     SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_SUCCESS                 99     [SSH-CONNECT]

And the instruction to close is recorded here:
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow

From the ssh2 protocol document:
2.1. connection: Channel write close extension "eow@openssh.com"

 The SSH connection protocol (rfc4254) provides the SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF
 message to allow an endpoint to signal its peer that it will send no
 more data over a channel. Unfortunately, there is no symmetric way for
 an endpoint to request that its peer should cease sending data to it
 while still keeping the channel open for the endpoint to send data to
 the peer.

Which appears to contradict...
Sep 15 13:45:43 fchannel sshd[3737651]: Received disconnect from xxx.132.xxx.107 port 53781:11: disconnected by user

But I think thats just the handshake mechanism for shutting down the connection - server says "I am done", client closes connection.
If this were simply a permissions error, a missing destination dir or missing local file, I would expect to see a message to that effect spat out on stderr along with your debug output. Something more esoteric is going on
In order to find out why the server closed the connection, the next step would be to enable full debugging on the sftp server. Your /etc/ssh/sshd_config should contain something like:
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

Change this to...
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -l DEBUG3

and see what logs you get....although its possible that the sftp-server is simply failing to start (you might want to check this with debsums -a -c openssh-server).

OK. Tried to enable DEBUG3, but didn't get any output in syslog. Probably not correctly configured to debug from my side. But, When I tried sftp in terminal, I get reply killed, so I concluded that sftp-server is not running for user. Tried with creating new user group named: sftp and user named: sftp_user and it worked. I can scp in sftp_user folder. However, stil no luck with original user. Tried to add him to sftp group but also get killed reply from system.

Judging from my own experience with the SSH protocol, I would guess it has something todo with double NAT between you and the remote server, since scp uses TCP sessions for communication.
TL;DR: See if you set a Keep Alive signal for your scp session.
Alternatively: Force IPv6 via the -6 option if available.

What I mean by double NAT is that your router do not get a public ip address on the WAN port, but rather a private ip address in the 100.64.0.0/10 range (as defined by RFC6598).
The router in your home can support in theory up to 65535 sessions through the NAT and the same applies to your ISP's NAT, although your ISP may have assigned a pool of public ip addresses to the carrier grade NAT.
In that case the supported number of sessions is 65535 * size of ip pool.
Now the trouble is that each ISP client may have more than one session going through their own NAT.
Think for instance your smart TV, cellphone and other people in your house using your WiFi and so on.
Multiply that with similar cases for all the other ISP clients and you may very well end up in a situation where the number of sessions needed is larger than the number of sessions supported by the carrier grade NAT.
Since not all people are using the Internet at the same time, you will see that the ISP is re-using port numbers and ip addresses for a different session and is therefore not pointed towards your router.
Why is the theory about sessions applicable for you?
It is because transfer of each individual file counts as a separate session.
Therefore you need to make scp send periodic a message about "I am not done yet" to keep TCP session open.
This is why you may experience the SSH session is crashing, when you log into the remote box.
Particularly if you have not done any interaction for a few minutes while being logged in via SSH.
One way to circumvent the chrasing is by having the following in your ~/.ssh/config file
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 10

What the setting does is that it send a signal every 10 second telling to keep the TCP session open.
You may want to tweak the setting, since I have experienced it may have to be as low as sending a keepalive signal every 5 seconds.
The alternative is of course to use IPv6, because NAT is not needed at all! :-)
However: Using a firewall will become more relevant in the IPv6 world since everything has a public ip address. :-)
